# address of operator and pointer operator

Tags: c++, pointers, addressof

What is the difference between following two function definitions?

Function declaration:

```
void fun(int* p);
```

Function Definition 1:

```
             void fun (int* p){
                       p += 1;
                      }
```

Function Definition 1:

```
                 void fun (*p){
                       p += 1;
                          }
```

Comment: Apart from the first being a function definition and the second being gibberish?

Comment: `void fun (&p)` is not the definition for `void fun(int* p);`. Even with `int`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for things that doesn't exist (elves, unicorns, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an `int` by pointer:

```
void fun (int* p) ;

void fun (int* p)
{
    *p += 1 ; // Add 1 to the value pointed by p.
}
```

Passing an `int` by [reference](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html):

```
void fun (int& p) ;

void fun (int& p)
{
    p += 1 ; // Add 1 to p.
}
```

Comment: int *p; p += 1 also works; it just does pointer arithmetic

Comment: @tenfour Judging by the question, I am assuming the OP does not know what pointer arithmetic is.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response I think I missed the return type of the parameter in 2nd definition.

Answer (score 2):

There's only **one** valid function definition, the 1st one you gave:

> Function Definition 1:

```
 void fun (int* p) {
    p += 1;
 }
```

Also you probably meant:

```
    (*p) += 1;
```

Comment: Sorry for this silly question. I was reading an article for 10 hours straight and in the end I got confused in function call with function definition.